# Video cut in half vertically XNA4 vs2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, xna-4.0

I loaded in a video in my XNA project and I got it to play. The only problem is it's cut in half vertically. The size of the video is 800x600 and the game is 800x600 as well. At first I accidently put a 640x480 version of the video in my Content but then I fixed it to 800x600. That didn't fix the 1/2 vertical though. I thought maybe the 640x480 xnb was still there and was being loaded. I tried looking for it and deleted whatever I thought was relate, but that didn't work as well. Here's a screenshot of the video in half.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
    namespace Bloxel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public int WIDTH = 800;
        public int HEIGHT = 600;

        Video splash;
        VideoPlayer player;
        Texture2D videoTexture;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = WIDTH;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = HEIGHT;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            splash = Content.Load<Video>("splash");
            player = new VideoPlayer();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            if (player.State == MediaState.Stopped)
            {
                player.IsLooped = false;
                player.Play(splash);
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            if (player.State != MediaState.Stopped)
                videoTexture = player.GetTexture();

            Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Y, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);

            if (videoTexture != null)
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(videoTexture, screen, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shot in the dark and I only mention because I recently saw this type of issue with a AAA title, do you have windows update [KB2803821](http://www.incgamers.com/2013/07/windows-7-kb2803821-update-issue-is-very-difficult-to-make-a-funny-headline-out-of) installed?

Comment: [Do you not know how to see a list of installed windows updates?](http://bit.ly/14P94Gv)

Comment: But it's cut horizontally…

Comment: I have installed that update. Is there a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike stated the issue is caused by a system update. In order to resolve this issue you will need to go into Windows Update and remove "Security Update for Windows 7 (KB2803821)". You can do this by simply right clicking the update and pressing delete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't if this will work, but you can try it: 
Change your rectangle to a vector in the draw function.

```
spriteBatch.Draw(videoTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
```

Because the Vector2 is zero, it will appear in the corner of your game screen.